# c# async and await error. Code not processing after await

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have started using async and await in c# and i have come along a problem, and get an error saying

`An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.`

I am using Entity Framework 6 and i have a base service which each service inherits from which looks like so

```
public BaseService(TEntity) where TEntity : class {
    private DataContext _context;

    public BaseService(DataContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity t)
    {
        if (_context.Entry<TEntity>(t).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(t);
        }

        _context.Entry<TEntity>(t).State = EntityState.Added;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return t;
    }
}
```

And i inherit from this base for UserService, PermissionService and GroupService

```
public class UserService : BaseService<User>
{
    public UserService(DataContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    public async Task AddToGroup(User user, Group group)
    {
        var userGroup = new UserGroup()
        {
            UserId = user.Id,
            User = user,
            GroupId = group.Id,
            Group = group
        };

        user.Groups.Add(userGroup);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class GroupService : BaseService<Group>
{
    public GroupService(DataContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    public async Task AddPermissionAsync(Group group, Permission permission)
    {
        var groupPermission = new GroupPermission()
        {
            GroupId = group.Id,
            Group = group,
            PermissionId = permission.Id,
            Permission = permission
        };

        group.Permissions.Add(groupPermission);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

}

public class PermissionService : BaseService<Permission>
{
    public PermissionService(DataContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

Now in my data initializer i have my seed method, and i need to call these async methods, so i have added the async property and it looks something like this

```
protected async override void Seed(DataContext context) {
    await AddPermissions(context);
    await AddGroups(context);
    await AddUsers(context);
    await AddPermissionsToGroups(context);
    await AddUsersToGroups(context);

    // ... more here
}

private async Task AddGroups(DataContext context)
    {
        var groupService = new GroupService(context);

        await groupService.AddAsync(new Group() { Name = "Admin" });
    }

    private async Task AddPermissions(DataContext context)
    {
        var permissionService = new PermissionService(context);

        await permissionService.AddAsync(new Permission("CanAdd", ""));
        await permissionService.AddAsync(new Permission("CanEdit", ""));
        await permissionService.AddAsync(new Permission("CanDelete", ""));
        await permissionService.AddAsync(new Permission("CanView", ""));

        ... more there about 10
    }

    private async Task AddUsers(DataContext context)
    {
        var userService = new UserService(context);

        await userService.AddAsync(new User() { UserName = "name@email.com" });
    }

    private async Task AddPermissionsToGroups(DataContext context)
    {
        var groupService = new GroupService(context);

        // add all permissions to admin
        var adminGroup = context.Groups.Where(e => e.Name == "Admin").FirstOrDefault();
        var permissions = context.Permissions.ToList();

        foreach (var item in permissions)
        {
            await groupService.AddPermissionAsync(adminGroup, item);
        }

    }

    private async Task AddUsersToGroups(DataContext context)
    {
        var userService = new UserService(context);
        var user = context.Users.Where(e => e.UserName == "name@mail.com").FirstOrDefault();
        var group = context.Groups.Where(e => e.Name == "Admin").FirstOrDefault();

        await userService.AddToGroup(user, group);
    }
}
```

Now once my initializer is called, only 1 permission is added to the database, nothing else happens.

Have i setup my async stuff correctly?

My understanding about async/await is that if i call a method like this

```
await my_async_method
```

Then this method will be called and nothing will process after it until this task has been completed.  In the method i am calling, i should have

```
public async Task my_async_method() {
    await MyCallAsync();
}
```

Do i need to have a return parameter of Task?  Should it be void?

Any guidance welcome

Comment: Where do you get the error and what is the exception's call stack?

Comment: This error is usually caused by an `async void` method, or improperly using an event-based asynchronous pattern (EAP) component. Try to create a minimal reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought EF6 would only allow one single async operation per `DbContext`. So you have to change your code to something like:

```
public async Task AddPermissionAsync(Group group, Permission permission)
{
  using(var context = new DbContext())
  {
    // do the add and save stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not quite right. `await` ensures that no other operation gets executed before the current one finishes. It's not `async/await` that cause an operation to execute asynchronously, they are what makes the code wait for an operation that is already asynchronous.